# EOFException while using readObject() method in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a message from the server. following is the piece of code:

```
try{

    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    J = new JChatComm(out , in,"client","server");

    String userInput = "Free for a chat?";

    JPacket p = new JPacket(userInput,"client");
    out.writeObject(p);


    p = (JPacket)in.readObject();


    if (!p.message.equals("Sure. Let us begin.")){
        System.out.println("Server seems to be unavailable.");
        socket.close();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Chat Initiated..");
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it gives the following output:

```
java.io.EOFException
at        
java.io.ObjectInp utStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2596)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1317)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at JClient.callServer(JClient.java:35)
at jtalkG24.main(jtalkG24.java:18)
```

Line 35 is the line which has the readObject() method.
I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going  wrong. You've reached the end of the stream. That's what the exception means. You have to catch it and react accordingly.